# visual studio, не работает live server

Tags: visual-studio-code

Изначально все работало ок.
Через некоторое время перестал работать live server.
Перезагрузка самой студии, компа и переустановка плагина не принели положительного результата.
Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

После запуска live server если проблема идентична моей то стоит зайти в исходный код страницы запускаемой и пролистать вниз найти этот скрипт и просто дописать его в свой проект, главное не забыть стереть перед сдачей проекта [image: screen]

Comment: Замените пожалуйста картинку на код текстом.